# GridView or ListView Realod or Refresh in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I tried to Refresh a GridView or ListView. any option available in Roku to reload/refresh a poster grid or Label List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, You just need to update their `content` field.